# Value for 'configPath' when running checkForServerUpgrade on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

To prepare my upgrade from mysql 5.7 to mysql 8, I want to run the [upgrade utility checker](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-upgrade.html). Here's what I did so far:

1. installed [mysqlsh](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install.html) on my machine
2. started mysqlsh
3. executed `util.checkForServerUpgrade` targeting the server that I want to upgrade

Here's the exact command that I used in step 3:

```
util.checkForServerUpgrade('root@my-remote-host:3306', { "password":"my-password" })
```

This runs fine but some checks are not executed because I don't provide the `configPath` parameter. For example, here's a warning that I get:

```
14) Removed system variables for error logging to the system log configuration
  To run this check requires full path to MySQL server configuration file to be specified at 'configPath' key of options dictionary
  More information:
    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-logging
```

Anybody knows the value that I should provide for the `configPath` parameter?

Comment: Need scan rds for upgrade, can you please mark/add the working solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting in the connection string, for example,

```
util.checkForServerUpgrade('root@localhost',{'configPath': '/etc/my.cnf'})
```

This worked for me, but without the connection string it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do the same using the command util.checkForServerUpgrade defining the configPath, without success. I then tried to run the same command directly from outside the mysqlsh shell, with success:

```
mysqlsh -- util check-for-server-upgrade root@localhost --target-version=8.0.13 --output-format=JSON --config-path=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and it worked. To be noted that when I've tried to run from mysqlsh in the session root@localhost the command:

```
util.checkForServerUpgrade({"configPath":"/etc/mysql/my.cnf"})
```

mysqlsh replied with:
"Util.checkForServerUpgrade: Argument #1: Invalid values in connection options: configPath (ArgumentError)"

Comment: FYI I had the  "Util.checkForServerUpgrade: Argument #1: Invalid values in connection options: configPath (ArgumentError)" error and I fixed it by calling it this way: `util.checkForServerUpgrade('root@localhost:3306', {"configPath":"/etc/mysql/my.cnf"})`